# Troubling linking UITextField to UITableViewCell subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, iboutlet

I am creating a view controller that holds a couple different fields for creating a log entry. To do this I have used a grouped table view with static cells, which looks like this:

[image]

Within each cell I have added a textfield (which has placeholder text as you can see from the screenshot). For the first text field I was able to create an IBOutlet for it using a subclass of UITableViewCell that I created, as seen below:

```
public class TextInputTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{

     @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

}
```

However, when I tried to do the same for the second cell, using the following class:

```
public class MultipleTextInputTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

}
```

It doesn't let me use-control click, or frankly any other method, to create an outlet for the text fields. I have tried setting the cell as a member of "MultipleTextInputTableViewCell" in the identity inspector, but that did not solve the problem. I have compared the two situations very closely and found no differences, so I am really confused to as why it isn't working for the second cell.

EDIT:

I was asked to post the attributes for the cell from the identity inspector. Below is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: have set the class of that cell as `MultipleTextInputTableViewCell` from identity inspector ?

Comment: @Lion sorry that's what I meant by "I have tried setting the cell as a member of "MultipleTextInputTableViewCell", but that did not solve the problem. "

Comment: and make sure that you are ctrl + dragging to that register class.

Comment: @Lion trust me that's not the issue, I've been at this for hours.

Comment: have delete any outlet after connect once?

Comment: @Lion I'm sorry I don't really understand your question

Comment: have you deleted any outlet from class which you have successfully connected once? for example if you deleted this  `@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!` from class.

Comment: @Lion I have not deleted any outlets from the `MultipleTextInputTableViewCell` class. I haven't been able to connect any outlets at all to it.

Comment: your cell type should be custom. check that also. if you use basic or other then also this kind of problem may occur

Comment: can you post screen shot with that cell selected ?

Comment: I am not found anything wrong in this. don't know how this kind of problem is occur. try other way to set outlet. use connection inspector or assistant editor to make outlet. that may work i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved my own answer, but Stack Overflow won't let me accept it for another two days.

From what I can tell, this is an Xcode bug.

By manually typing out each outlet and then dragging the connection circle in the line-counter to each text field I was able to connect them. However, I tried it the other way around (option-click dragging from a text field to the written code) and that still didn't work. I am using assistant editor capability to do this so the issue may lie there.

EDIT:

Also, what actually would have been the accepted answer from me that I just found out (a couple hours later after I posted this question) is that you can create an @IBOutlet directly in the view controller holding the table view if you are using static cells. There is no need to create subclasses for each cell, and I guess Xcode is discouraging it through not allowing it to be easily connected. This connection works both ways and greatly simplifies my project. But kudos to myself I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If one both cell are not static then it is possible. If you are use static cell then you can't use dynamic.

I think you should use dynamic prototype cell instead of static cells. It may resolve your problem :)

Comment: But the whole point of using static cells is because if I use dynamic, then I still can't connect a text field because of the infamous error that "iboutlets cannot be connected to repeating content" so this doesn't solve my problem. I'm currently undecided as to whether or not I should DV this answer.

Comment: No, if you make class for every cell which is subclass of `UITablevieCell` and set it from identity inspector then you can connect outlet. you will not get that error.

Comment: Okay fair enough, that's my misunderstanding. However, I really just need a solution for static cells.